# how to display cursor position in the Textarea using jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net

How to get cursor position of line number,column number and character number in the Textarea character index in asp.net using jquery

Thanks & Regards

Comment: [jquery with fun make your school board](http://www.jquery2dotnet.com/2013/06/jquery-your-school-board.html)

Comment: that is no where useful to me in my project

Comment: what you are trying to do past some code or provide [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/S6ySC/1/

Comment: i am unable to get the output plz help me http://jsfiddle.net/S6ySC/1/

Comment: i had taken reference from http://geekswithblogs.net/svanvliet/archive/2005/03/24/textarea-cursor-position-with-javascript.aspx   that is in html language , and i am integrating in asp.net using visual studio plz help with changes

Comment: may be try this one or you have to modify code http://jsfiddle.net/hgDwx/

Comment: try this one http://jsfiddle.net/42zHC/18/